# User Role in Grafana is reverting to Viewer

Tags: azure-active-directory, grafana, user-permissions

#### Description

Having Grafana `v7.3.6` deployed in Kubernetes, and integrated with `Azure AD` for logging in.

There is a user that initially had the `Viewer` role assigned and it's been a while since we decided to assign him the `Editor` or `Admin` Role instead of `Viewer`.

Changing the permission from Grafana Web-UI works fine as expected, but after like 7 or 10 days, it reverts back to Viewer.

PS. Our AzureAD specialist stated that he has updated the Azure configs/roles relevant to that user.

##### What I have tried

- I have tried both `Editor` and `Admin` roles but no matter what it is being reverted.
- I have tried to restart the Grafana POD (After updating the Role) and see if it can cause the permissions to be reverted but it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct:

> On every login the user organization role will be reset to match AzureAD’s application role and their organization membership will be reset to the default organization.

Doc: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/azuread/#map-roles

Configure proper role mapping, so user will have desired role in the AD.

Or [skip that org role sync](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/azuread/#skip-organization-role-sync) and manage roles via UI.

You have quite old Grafana, so you may need to upgrade it to use all mentioned Grafana Azure AD config options.